# Show Rows as Columns using Join and Select Statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to combine multiple rows into one. Below is an example. My actual data has quite a few more rows and a lot more columns, but I've condensed it. I also only need certain rows/columns included. The problem I'm running into is if I can get my rows into columns, it still shows extra rows that shouldn't be there.

This is what I get if I `SELECT * FROM Employees`:

| ID | Profile | Priority | Location | Commissions | Review |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Remote | Supervisor | 0 | Minnesota | N | N |
| Remote | Supervisor | 3 | New York | N | N |
| Remote | Manager | 0 | Vermont | Y | N |
| Remote | Manager | 0 | Iowa | N | Y |
| Remote | Manager | 0 | Wyoming | N | N |
| Remote | Manager | 3 | Iowa | N | N |
| Remote | Manager | L | Iowa | Y | N |
| Remote | Worker | 0 | Vermont | Y | N |
| Remote | Worker | 0 | Iowa | N | Y |
| Remote | Worker | 0 | Wyoming | N | N |
| Remote | Worker | 1 | Iowa | N | N |
| Remote | Worker | 3 | Iowa | N | N |
| Remote | Leader | 1 | Iowa | N | N |
| Remote | Leader | 2 | Oregon | N | N |

What I want Is one row for the Manger and another row for the Worker and the rest of information as columns (I need The Manger & Work Profiles. Priority 0 & Location and Commissions Columns for the Remote ID)

| Profile | Location | Commissions | Location | Commissions | Location | Commissions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manager | Vermont | Y | Iowa | N | Wyoming | N |
| Worker | Vermont | N | Iowa | N | Wyoming | Y |

I've gotten this query to work on a small scale with a table that had very minimal info, but it's not working on a bigger scale. I'm guessing it's because I didn't properly tell my query what to include/exclude but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT EE.ID, EE.Profile, vtm.Location, vtm.Commissions, iam.Location, iam.Commissions, wmm.Location, wmm.Commissions
FROM Employees EE
Left OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, Profile, Location, Commissions FROM Employees WHERE Location = 'Vermont' AND Profile      = 'Manager') vtm
    ON EE.ID = vtm.ID
Left OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, Profile, Location, Commissions FROM Employees WHERE Location = 'Iowa' AND Profile =   'Manager') iam
    ON vtm.ID = iam.ID
Left OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, Profile, Location, Commissions FROM Employees WHERE Location = 'Wyoming' AND Profile = 'Manager') wmm
    ON iam.ID = wmm.ID
WHERE EE.ID = 'Remote' AND Priority = '0'
```

Comment: You have PL/SQL in title and tags, but do you really want to use Oracle's programming language PL/SQL here? So far it looks like you are looking for a solution in SQL.

Comment: It's for software I use at work. I was told it uses PL/SQL but that most SQL queries work on it. There are certain things (like join statements) that can't be done in the traditional SQL way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get this result:

```
select
  profile,
  'Vermont' as location_1,
  max(case when location = 'Vermont' then commissions end) as commissions_1,
  'Iowa' as location_2,
  max(case when location = 'Iowa' then commissions end) as commissions_2,
  'Wyoming' as location_3,
  max(case when location = 'Wyoming' then commissions end) as commissions_3
from employees
where profile in ('Manager', 'Worker') and id = 'Remote' and priority = '0'
group by profile
order by profile;
```

Instead of having a column where all rows show the same location, you can make the location the commisions title of course:

```
select
  profile,
  max(case when location = 'Vermont' then commissions end) as vermont,
  max(case when location = 'Iowa'    then commissions end) as iowa,
  max(case when location = 'Wyoming' then commissions end) as wyoming
from employees
where profile in ('Manager', 'Worker') and id = 'Remote' and priority = '0'
group by profile
order by profile;
```

Another option to address this task would be a `PIVOT` clause.

Comment: Is there a way to expand on the Conditional Aggregate, or maybe the PIVOT clause would be better.  Let's say later down the road I want to view commissions for Priority 0, but Review for Priority 2 . Is there a way to do that and still keep just the single row for Worker and Manager? I have a lot of random information I'm trying to join together with as few rows as possible. I understand how to expand Select/Join queries but my knowledge outside that is limited.

Comment: Well, use `AND` if you want to narrow down the results. E.g. `max(case when location = 'Vermont' and priority = 0 then commissions end) as vermont`, You'd have to remove `and priority = '0'` from your `WHERE` clause of course in order to also get other priorities.